# Is Python's `list(some_dictionary)` thread-safe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

If `d` is a dictionary, then apparently CPython does not like it if another thread modifies d while

```
[k for k in d]
```

is evaluated. How about using

```
list(d)
```

instead? Is this thread-safe?

Comment: Don't rely on CPython implementation details. Use actual synchronization.

Comment: Python doesn't like it if the *same* thread modifies `d` under that condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fully with @user2357112, this is an implementation detail and you should not rely on it. But for the sake of answering the question: The relevant `list` and `dict` methods are written in C, hence the call is a single bytecode operation, and [the code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bdf04552f4df/Objects/listobject.c#l2291) does not release the GIL directly or indirectly, as far as I can tell. Therefore **in current CPython** no other Python thread can interrupt the `list` call and modify `d`.

Note that this breaks down if either `list` has been replaced with something else, or `d` is not an actual honest-to-god `dictobject` written in C. Also note that "is written in C" is not a sufficient condition, for example many collection operations call comparison/hashing methods and thus execute arbitrary Python code, allowing the GIL to be released.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the `dict` iterator doesn't release the GIL. Calling `list` on an object whose iterator is written in Python, or whose iterator might invoke Python code, can be interrupted by a GIL release.

Comment: @user2357112 Good point, added that along with other caveats and clarifications.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I do of course agree that explicit locking would be better, especially because of the dependence on the type of `d`.